# use dft for image processing in matlab with out matlab function

Tags: matlab, dft

I have 2 function in matlab

```
%%%%%%% test_dft 
clc;clear all;close all;
%%


  img=(imread('images/test_image.jpg'));
if isrgb(img)
    a=double(rgb2gray(img));
else
    a=double(img);
end
temp = zeros(size(a));
f = double(zeros(size(a)));
[m n]=size(a)
for i = 1:m
    temp(:,i)=dft(a(:,i));
 end
for j = 1:n
   f(j,:) = dft(a(j,:));
end


%%%%%%%% dft.m
function X=dft(x1) 
N=length(x1);
X=zeros(size(x1)); 
i=sqrt(-1); 
for k=0:N-1 
for n=0:N-1 
X(k+1)=(X(k+1)+x1(n+1)*exp(-2*pi*i*k*n/N)) ;
end 
end
end
```

I wanna calculate dft of image and after that use it for masking in frequency domain( with out matlab function ).
this code tacks long time, but it doesn't work. I don't know why .

Answer (score 0):

`imread` returns integer values. Convert them to double first.

```
a = double(a);
```

Comment: thank you but now shows this error:??? Attempted to access temp(32,:); index out of bounds because size(temp)=[31,34].

Error in ==> test_el_dft at 18
   f(j,:) = dft(temp(j,:));

Comment: Try to run `x=dft(temp(j,:));` What is the size of `x`? What is the size of `a`?

Comment: I found my answare, I changed m and n (index of for) in def.m----thank you for your help me @yuk